# Why almost every question gets an upvote now?

Tags: discussion, voting

I mean, questions like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84537/how-to-add-captcha-as-cck-field) - one sentence, no research effort, no basic understanding, 3 concepts / APIs mangled together and it still got upvote. Un-upvoted soon, but it was there.

Or [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84531/filefield-sources-module-error) - deleted now, but was clearly off-topic, bug report and it had it in it's title. And got upvoted.

And there are many more each day.

Is there any reward for upvoting? Some badge? Something that encourages upvoting without reading?

Comment: both the posts are deleted and may be 10K can see

Comment: It's on the radar - I won't say any more about it for now :)

Comment: Thanks @Clive - if they are legitimate upvotes I simply don't agree with, so be it, but I'm glad someone competent is looking at this situation.

Comment: hahahahah @ competent. Thanks that made my day ;)

Comment: @Clive did I get my dictionary wrong? It says it means about "someone who knows what he is doing, with sufficient skill and privileges".

Comment: Your English is spot on - the idea that I'm considered competent deeply amuses me =P

Comment: @Clive any news? It seems it's almost a custom that everything from new users gets upvote now. like [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/89992/16495) - plain bugreport, but upvoted. And many more :| I mean, we can deal with this post, with each one to be honest, but it seems strange to see it at mass scale, and First Posts queue always appears empty...

Comment: @Mołot Suffice to say there's nothing 'dodgy' going on. One or more people seem to be upvoting questions regardless of quality, there's not really anything we can do about that besides countering with downvotes, and leaving a more verbose comment so the OP doesn't pick up the bad habit. Not ideal, I know, but as long as voting isn't targeted at/against specific people, users are free to vote for whatever reason they like. Such is democracy I guess :)

Comment: @Clive oh, OK. If it is so, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if voted on 600 question, you will get **Electorate** badge

> see this
>   https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate

```
Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.
```

Comment: But you can downvote them and get Electorate as well!

Comment: Yes I know that, I updated the answer and i think because of this badge, users vote the question or may be some of them like that question too.

Comment: Seems they don't, if they are in fact badge hunters...

Comment: Of Course, No one can't stop them.